# Problem installing rspec-1.3.2 on Lion using RVM and ruby 1.8.6

Tags: ruby, rspec, rvm, osx-lion

I'm trying to install rspec version 1.3.2 on OS X Lion using RVM and Ruby 1.8.6

When I install, I get the following:

```
$ gem install rspec -v=1.3.2
Abort trap: 6
```

I'm able to successfully install the same rspec version using the system ruby. I've tried to do some research into the problem, but it doesn't look like anybody has run into the same thing. Similar questions have suggested `export CC=gcc-4.2` before installing ruby. I tried that (after completely blowing away RVM and reinstalling the latest version, 1.6.31 right now) but it had no effect.

Has anyone else else encountered this? Have you found a solution?

Comment: Have you tried upgrading to Ruby 1.8.7? It's possible just doing that will fix your problem.

Comment: I'm using RVM specifically so I can run 1.8.6. It's a legacy app that uses 1.8.6 on the server, so I want my development environment to match. I checked and using 1.8.7 does indeed solve the problem, so perhaps it's just a 1.8.6 issue rather than an RVM issue. But unfortunately, I still need to solve it in 1.8.6.

Comment: I was successfully able to install rspec-1.3.1 which may be close enough.

Comment: Ok..good. You can always try to play with a lower gem version, because higher gem versions probably break on 1.8.6. Use `gem update --system x.y.z` to change gem versions. Keep in mind though you might want to back up stuff when you do it. Anyway..good that you got 1.3.1 up.

Comment: However, you should seriously consider upgrading to 1.9.3.

Comment: @Agis your comment is a little unconstructive. rvm is providing the ability to install many different ruby versions in parallel. Especially if you have to work on a legacy application like [Emily](http://stackoverflow.com/users/105938/emily) said ...

Answer (score 1):

I installed 1.8.6 fresh with no gems and installed with verbose flag...

```
gem install rspec -v=1.3.2 --verbose
GET http://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://production.s3.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz
200 OK
Installing gem rspec-1.3.2
Abort trap: 6
```

I see the problem of Abort Trap 6 seems to indicate that some dependency is missing.  I was hoping that this would get resolved with the pristine command, but settled on just going down a version.

```
rvm gemset pristine
gem install rspec -v=1.3.1 --verbose
...
Successfully installed rspec-1.3.1
...
gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

rake (0.9.2)
rspec (1.3.1)
```

Why must you use 1.3.2 instead of 1.3.1?  Hope this helps.